# conan.io - header only package

Tags: c++, conan

I'm trying to create a simple demo **header only library** called *foo* and require it another library called *bar*.

The structure of *foo* is this:

**foo/include/foo.hpp** - just a test header file...

**foo/conanfile.py**

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake

class FooConan(ConanFile):
    name = "foo"
    version = "0.0.1"
    exports = "*"
```

export it using:

```
conan export steazzalini/testing
```

**bar/conanfile.txt**

```
[requires]
foo/0.0.1@steazzalini/testing

[generators]
cmake
```

*conan install* fails saying:

```
ERROR: Can't find a 'foo/0.0.1@steazzalini/testing' package for the specified options and settings

- Try to build from sources with "--build foo" parameter
- If it fails, you could try to contact the package author , report your configuration and try to collaborate to support it.

Package configuration:
- Settings:
- Options:
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: This doesn't *look* like c++.

Comment: @ScottHunter conan.io is a package manager for c++

Comment: @ScottHunter It's relative to conan, a C++ package manager. Anyway I agree that it might be better tagged with `python` and/or conan (if it has a tag)

Comment: @steazzalini Even if it's header-only you still have to package it up, see: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/324

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a minor clarification, I guess you meant that library *foo* is required by *bar*.

Every package has to be created, even if it is a header only library. When you `conan export` it copies the source code into the recipe (the other alternative would be using the `source()` method to retrieve the source code), but the package still has to be created.

The `build()` method is not necessary, as there is nothing to build, but you should add the `package()` method to your recipe, something like:

```
def package(self):
   self.copy("*.h", dst="include", src="include")
```

Then you have to create the package. This can be done with several methods, one would be to install the *foo* package:

```
$ conan install foo/0.0.1@steazzalini/testing --build
```

But this is typically not necessary, as you can also build it when calling the install from the consumer project (the *bar* one):

```
$ conan install . --build
```

There is also an option, the `build_policy` that can be added to recipes, and is well suited for header only libraries. It can be `missing` or `always`. The latter is useful when creating packages from the latest git (master/head..) commit of a project. Using this policy, the consumers doesn't have to explicitely call `--build` to specify that the package has to be created. So the recipe could be something like:

```
from conans import ConanFile, CMake

class FooConan(ConanFile):
    name = "foo"
    version = "0.0.1"
    exports = "*"
    build_policy = "missing"

    def package(self):
       self.copy("*.h", dst="include", src="include")
```

Finally, you might be interested in the `$ conan new foo/0.0.1@steazzalini/testing -i` command, that will create a `conanfile.py` for you with some of these things. The `-t` option for such command is useful to create a `test_package`, a utility for creating and testing packages, to ensure the package is correct. Have a look at http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/packaging/testing.html#automatically-creating-and-testing-packages

UPDATE: conan docs got a new section specific for header-only libraries: http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/header_only.html